# Ignore field from database Spring Roo

Tags: database, json, spring, entity, spring-roo

I have a spring roo web service that I am currently building out but I have an entity that contains a field that should not be included in the database.

I would like the field to be in the entity and print it out with JSON to string methods, but I don't need that value saved. Is there any annotation or hack to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Roo uses JPA for persistence. You want to mark the field as [@Transient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html):

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooEntity
class MyEntity {

    private String column1;

    @Transient
    private String ignoreMe; // Ignore this field in JPA

}
```

You can also use the same annotation for bean *methods* that would otherwise be mapped:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooEntity
class MyEntity {

    private String column1;

    @Transient
    private String getAsJSON() {
        return JSONHelper.toJSON(column1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'

Comment: That error means you likely have a JavaBean with a constraint that is not being adhered to. Catch the `ConstraintViolationException` that is thrown, and inspect the contents of `getConstraintViolations()`. The error shouldn't be related to the solution I posted above though.